# Are questions about writing about programming on topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

Is [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392686/organic-arcs-of-different-sizes-and-timescales/27393745), which asked for clarification on the use of the word "arc" in a programming blog, on topic?

This type of question isn't explicitly covered in the [Stack Overflow scope document](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Migrating it to [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) is probably more "correct", but it is really unlikely that those folks would understand that the OP was confusing "arc" with Automatic Reference Counting, a programming term.

Comment: Doesn't look to me like the OP was aware of "Automatic Reference Counting" in any way and it was also not the answer. The whole question and solution is simply one of English Language Usage and is only incidentally related to programming. In other words: seems entirely off-topic to me.

Comment: @deceze The OP tagged the question with Automatic-Ref-Counting

Comment: That probably just popped up as the first suggestion when he entered "arc" in the tag field, nothing more.

Comment: And it's on hold. Funny how these things happen. This looked very much off topic. I have visited English Language & Usage on a few occasions, and they are fairly strict about what questions they like, and how they need to be written. So simply moving the question would probably not end well.

Comment: It's definitely off topic, and no, it's not about **writing** about programming as your title suggests, it's about **reading** about programming. My first thougth was, it would be on topic on Writers.SE, but when I've clicked on the link, it was 'hell no'. English.SE or ELL.SE would be the correct site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, that question is off-topic for the same reasons that questions about the best keyboard or chair for programmers would be off-topic. You might be programming when you're sitting on the chair and typing on the keyboard, but those two activities (sitting and typing) aren't *programming*. The OP of this post might have been reading about programming when he thought of his question, but answering an EL&U question isn't really helping him solve a specific programming problem.

Also, I don't think the OP is confusing the word "arc" with the concept of automatic reference counting here. He probably used the tag [arc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arc) which is a synonym for [automatic-ref-counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/automatic-ref-counting), so it would have been converted automatically.